# Node.js (npm) accessing files inside installed module

Tags: node.js, npm

I am implementing a Node module and I'd like the users to optionally be able to `require` some files part of the module. For example :

```
var M = require('my-module');
var Foo = require('my-module/foo');
```

Considering that my module structure is like this :

```
./my-module
  +- lib
  |  +- foo
  |  |  +- index.js
  |  +- index.js
  +- package.json
```

And this is the basic `package.json` file :

```
{
  "name": "my-module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My very own super fun module.",
  "main": "lib/index.js"
}
```

**Note**: unecessary keys were omitted for clarity, ex: `dependencies`, `keywords`, `author`, etc.

How would the `package.json` can be modified to allow this "feature"?

Comment: nodeload has similar thing where you can load modules from lib folders - https://github.com/benschmaus/nodeload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your module structure to this:

```
./my-module
  +- lib
  |  +- foo
  |  |  +- index.js
  |  +- index.js
  +- index.js
  +- foo.js
  +- package.json
```

Or even better, change `require('my-module/foo')` to `require('my-module').Foo` like most of the modules do.

Setting `main` in package.json is a wrong thing to do (because package.json is npm's own metadata and shouldn't have anything to do with node.js, think about installing the package from bower for example), so you shouldn't be using that anyway.

Comment: Actually, Node does check package.json files for a `main` key, and loads that file for the module.

Comment: Yes it does. But it **requires** package.json to be present, and be a valid JSON, which is unnecessary and is not always true.

Comment: Agreed. But as long as you have the package.json, there's nothing *wrong* with using it, right?

Comment: It would work as expected with the default node.js loader if that's what you asking.

Comment: @alex then why [nodeload](github.com/benschmaus/nodeload) doesn't have what you are suggesting (project structure) but still works as documented? (i.e. `require('nodeload/monitoring')`, `require('nodeload/reporting')`, etc.)

Comment: I don't know why it works, and don't really care. We have been discussing this approach in [mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/pull/1077) and decided against it. Nodeload is just an example of a bad api design, but I suppose it would work for somebody.